# How to access contents of ui from a external function?

Tags: c++, qt

.h

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    Ui::MainWindowClass ui;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

};
```

.cpp

```
    void Test()
    {
        MainWindow mw;
        mw.ui.pushButton->move(QPoint(200, 200));
        qDebug() << "test" << "\n";
    }



    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        ui.setupUi(this);
    
        QShortcut *shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_Q), this);
        QObject::connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, this, &Test);
        return;
    }
```

How to access the contents of `ui` from the class `MainWindow` in the function `Test` without making `Test` a child/inherit `MainWindow`?

I think the way i did is not working as when the function is called with the shortcut the button isnt moved.

Comment: Simply pass the pointer you need in your external function (for whatever reason) - basic c++, nothing Qt related here.

Answer (score 0):

Qt compiles ui files into *ui_<ui_name>.h* (you can see them in your build folder).
So you can use ui just include ui_<ui_name>.h

Example

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private:

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    w.ui->progressBar->setValue(30);

    return a.exec();
}
```